# When trying to set a django session value, I have Type Error "Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable" while it is a string value. Why?

Tags: python, json, django, session, typeerror

I would like to record a discount code from input users. I have set up a UserDiscountForm(forms.Form) (in *forms.py*). In the view, I would like to record in the session, the data that a user inputs. But when I try to set the value (after checking that the form is valid), it raises a TypeError: "Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable". I don't understand because the data I am trying to save is a string value. In addition, I am able to save other data in the session (a shopping cart and a shipping address) the similar way and it works perfectly.

#### *forms.py*

(user_input is a string)

```
from django import forms

class UserDiscountForm(forms.Form):
    user_discount = forms.CharField(label='discount code ?', label_suffix="-->", help_text="Entrez discount code", required=False)

    def clean_user_discount(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_input = self.cleaned_data['user_discount']

        if len(user_input) > 4:
            raise forms.ValidationError("longueur > 4")
        
        else:
            print(type(user_input))
            return user_input
```

#### *views.py*

(form.cleaned_data['user_discount'] is a string)

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import JsonResponse

from . basket import Basket
from store.models import Product
from discount.forms import UserDiscountForm


def basket_summary(request):
    basket = Basket(request)
    form = UserDiscountForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {'basket':basket, 'form':form}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data['user_discount'])
            print(type(form.cleaned_data['user_discount']))
            request.session['discount_code'] = form.cleaned_data['user_discount']
            form = UserDiscountForm()
            context = {'basket':basket, 'form':form}
            return render(request,"store/basket_summary.html",context)
        else:
            return render(request,"store/basket_summary.html",context)
    else:
        return render(request,"store/basket_summary.html",context)
```

#### Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/basket/

Django Version: 3.2
Python Version: 3.9.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'store',
 'account',
 'basket',
 'orders',
 'payment',
 'contact',
 'address',
 'discount',
 'shipping']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\Environments\monoi_django_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\Environments\monoi_django_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 119, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\Environments\monoi_django_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\middleware.py", line 61, in process_response
    request.session.save()
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\Environments\monoi_django_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py", line 83, in save
    obj = self.create_model_instance(data)
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\Environments\monoi_django_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py", line 70, in create_model_instance
    session_data=self.encode(data),
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\Environments\monoi_django_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py", line 114, in encode
    return signing.dumps(
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\Environments\monoi_django_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\signing.py", line 110, in dumps
    return TimestampSigner(key, salt=salt).sign_object(obj, serializer=serializer, compress=compress)
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\Environments\monoi_django_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\signing.py", line 172, in sign_object
    data = serializer().dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\Environments\monoi_django_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\signing.py", line 87, in dumps
    return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':')).encode('latin-1')
  File "c:\users\utilisateur\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "c:\users\utilisateur\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "c:\users\utilisateur\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "c:\users\utilisateur\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '

Exception Type: TypeError at /basket/
Exception Value: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable
```

I have a ShippingAddressForm(forms.ModelForm) which works well. Here is the view associated to it.

#### *views.py*

```
def check_existing_shipping_address(request):
    try:
        shipping_address_form_id = request.session['shipping-form-id']
        return redirect('address:update_shipping_address')
    except:
        return redirect('address:create_shipping_address')


def create_shipping_address(request):
    form = ShippingAddressForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {'form':form}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            shipping_form = form.save()
            request.session['shipping-form-id'] = shipping_form.pk
            shipping_form = ShippingAddressForm()            
            return redirect('payment:checkout')
        else:
            return render(request,"payment/shipping_address.html",context)
    else:
        return render(request,"payment/shipping_address.html",context)
```

#### Class Basket in *basket.py*

```
from decimal import Decimal

from store.models import Product

class Basket():

    def __init__(self, request):

        self.session = request.session
        basket = self.session.get('cart')

        if 'cart' not in request.session:
            basket = self.session['cart'] = {}

        self.basket = basket



    def save(self):
        self.session.modified = True



    def add(self, product, qty):
        """
        Adding and updating basket session data
        """
        product_id = str(product.id)

        if product_id not in self.basket:
            self.basket[product_id] = {'price': float(product.price), 'qty':int(qty)}

        else:
            self.basket[product_id]['qty'] = qty

        self.save()


    def add_new(self, product):
        """
        Adding new item in basket session data
        """
        product_id = str(product.id)

        if product_id not in self.basket:
            self.basket[product_id] = {'price': float(product.price), 'qty':1}

        else:
            pass

        self.save()



    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Collect the product_id in the session data to query the database and return products
        """
        
        product_ids = self.basket.keys()
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        basket = self.basket.copy()

        for product in products:
            basket[str(product.id)]['product'] = product
    
        for item in basket.values():
            item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
            item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['qty']
    
            yield item


    def __len__(self):
        """
        Get the basket data and count the quantity of all items
        """
                        
        return sum(item['qty'] for item in self.basket.values())


    def get_total_price(self):

        return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['qty'] for item in self.basket.values())


    def get_subtotal_price(self, product):
        product_id = str(product)

        return self.basket[product_id]['qty'] * self.basket[product_id]['price']



    def delete(self, product):
        """
        Delete item from session data
        """
        product_id = str(product)

        if product_id in self.basket:
            del self.basket[product_id]
        
        self.save()


    def update(self, product, qty):
        """
        Update item in session data
        """
        product_id = str(product)

        if product_id in self.basket:
            self.basket[product_id]['qty'] = qty
        
        self.save()


    def clear(self):
        
        try:
            del self.session['cart']
        except KeyError:
            pass

        self.save()
```

Comment: Please [edit] and add the _full_ error traceback to your question.

Comment: I have added traceback.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct form `UserDiscountForm`, perhaps you have another form with the same name that you are using by mistake?

Comment: I have double checked. I have only one form called UserDiscountForm. 

I want to specify something.
- forms.py is inside an app called "discount"
- views.py is inside an app called "basket"
I do not thing this is a problem...

Comment: Can you share the `Basket` class?

Comment: I have added basket.py to show Basket class.